# Understanding the separation in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, factory-pattern

I've been learning a lot about MVVM recently, but haven't yet grasped everything - my biggest problem is:

> What qualifies and what doesn't qualify as total Model View ViewModel separation, and how to see that "border"?

I'll try to discuss my concern based on the project that I'm working on right now.

**1. The case**

Let's say we have a MainWindow with plenty of buttons, each of them opening a 'specific' new Window.

Note: For DI I'm using an IoC container (Castle Windsor).

MainWindow has its own ViewModel that further has its own Model. Our IoC container initializes it on app startup.

We also have a TypedFactory (or any other factory) that we want for creation of other MVVM objects.

Now, important part: When we press the button, we want a new window to open. If it wasn't MVVM, one could (not should) call the window creation in the ViewModel itself, just by doing:

```
WindowX ourNewWindow = new WindowX();
ourNewWindow.Show();
```

But, this is MVVM and we should strictly avoid referencing our View inside a ViewModel. Thus, we can delegate the creation process to our Factory.

We could do that by injecting the Factory into our ViewModel constructor and tell that Factory to create the View for us.

```
private IFactory _factory;
public ViewModel(IFactory factory)
{
    _factory = factory;
}

public void OpenWindow()
{
    var newWindow = _factory.Create<NewView>();
    newWindow.Show();
}
```

Still, that doesn't feel right to me (correct me if I'm wrong) since we are still referencing our new View inside a ViewModel.

So, we can add another layer of indirection, be it WindowMnager. Have that windowManager have IFactory as dependency and delegate all processes of window creation and management to it.

But, for me it still feels like there is a link between the View and the ViewModel that shouldn't be there. Or am I completely wrong and approaching the case incorrectly?

Thus, the final question is:

> When does that forementioned "link" between Vie and ViewModel disappear and at which point do we stop creating more and more indirection levels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Still, that doesn't feel right to me (correct me if I'm wrong) since we are still referencing our new View inside a ViewModel.

No, the view model actually knows nothing about the windows. It only knows about a factory *interface* (or a "window service" interface or whatever you choose to call it). It is the *implementation* of this interface that actually creates the windows and you could easily replace the implementation with another one without affecting the view model.

This is the beauty of dependency injection. The important thing here is that the view model only has a dependency upon an interface so there is no *direct* coupling between the view model and the view. The class that implements the interface could for example easily be defined in a view specific project/assembly and the interface itself and the view model could be implemented in a view model project/assembly and unit tested separately without any windows actually being created.

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you very much! Now I literally have all my "mental-design" solved!

Comment: Also - when I close the windows (they have lifestyleTransient) should I override OnClosing and release the View there, or is it already implemented by the container?

Comment: There is no reason to dispose the views unless they implement the IDisposable interface. The built-in elements don't.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would've approached it:

- Send a message from the MainViewModel
- Have a handler registered to that message which will handle the opening of the window.

That way the actual process triggered is separated from the action.